# pyramid framework on raspberry pi

Tags: python, web-server

Before I buy a raspberry pi ( being honest ), I'd like to know if it is
possible to run a pyramid python framework from raspberry Pi. If so, then how ?

I know LAMP runs on it but at present I am looking particularly for a python framework.

Comment: Web frameworks don't require anything special besides the internet, it's hard to see why it would not.

Answer (score 1):

Python is the official development environment on the raspberry pi, and pyramid is a python framework, so that should work just dandy.

Though be aware that the raspberry pi is a small computer, also in terms of processing power, so if you plan to host something big or serve many clients, it might not be a good choice. As a development environment, it should be great!

Comment: *"Python is the official development environment on the raspberry pi"* -> **According to whom?!??**

Comment: According to the Raspberry Pi Foundation: 'Does it have an official programming language? The Raspberry Pi Foundation recommends Python as a language for learners.' http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#softwareLanguages

Comment: Seems a little ambiguous but fair enough.  I just would not want people to take that to mean that the foundation provides any official resources or support for such (that they don't provide for a bunch of other languages anyway, e.g. the programming forums are not python centric).  So personally I'd word that *officially recommended by*.  Anyway, splitting hairs: +1, pyramid is apparently a web framework written in python, no reason it shouldn't run on the pi.

Comment: Well, I do think it is a bit silly to talk about an official development environment for a linux computer, and perhaps I am over interpreting their wording.